# Как избежать Access to Script from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Ребят, скачал open-sourse файл HTML/CSS/JS, а там - игра. Хотел её поиграть, разобраться в коде. Открываю index.html и вижу голый HTML без стилизации и скрипта. После меня осенило посмотреть консоль, где меня ждала вот эта надпись

> Access to Script at
>   'file:///C:/Users/User/Downloads/Desktop/Tower%20Blocks/tower_blocks_script.js'
>   from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Invalid response.
>   Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Помогите, пожалуйста: что делать? Можно ли от этого избавиться и если да, то как?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто вы запускаете сайт из своей локальной файловой системы. Для инициации Cross-origin запроса браузер клиента добавляет в HTTP запрос Origin (домен сайта, с которого происходит запрос). В случае локальной ФС - это null. Доступ с такого адреса запрещен политикой.

Если короче, то подгрузка скриптов с файловой системы блокируется в целях безопасности. Настройте себе локальный веб-сервер.