# Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: javascript, модули

Экспорт отказывается работать, выдается ошибка Unexpected token 'export'. Облазил весь интернет, ничего не нашел.

Суть в том, чтобы передать два параметра (player.health и enemy.health) из файла player.js в mechanics.js. var используется для того, чтобы переменную было видно из-под объектов, не бейте за него. Никаких расширений, библиотек, фреймворков не использую (кроме Jquery, но в малом кол-ве)

player.js (откуда передать):

```
var getPlayerHealthForMechanics = player.health;
var getEnemyHealthForMechanics = enemy.health;
  } //cкобка от объекта сверху
};//cкобка от объекта сверху
export { getPlayerHealthForMechanics, getEnemyHealthForMechanics };
```

mechanics.js (куда передать):

```
import {getPlayerHealthForMechanics, getEnemyHealthForMechanics} from './player.js'
let timer = function() {
  if (getPlayerHealthForMechanics > 0 && getEnemyHealthForMechanics <= 0) {
    myTimer = setInterval(game.makeFightEnviroment, 5000);
  }
};
```

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/modules-intro

Comment: @grime Да я уж смотрел там, не получается

Comment: в index.html <script src="./player.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="./mechanics.js" type="module"></script>

Comment: @grime Выдает сразу 2 ошибки:
Access to script at 'file:///E:/code/.arofle/player.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
game.html:66 
GET file:///E:/code/.arofle/player.js net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/867769/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-access-to-script-from-origin-null-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy

Comment: в vscode есть функция GO LIVE, которая имитирует создание сервера или создает его

Comment: @grime Ну вроде открыл через локальный сервер, теперь
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' (две ошибки сразу)

Comment: А умеет ли ваш браузер модули?

Comment: @AlexeyTen точно не знаю, но вроде пользуюсь оперой последних версий и, чисто логически, она должна это делать